# OpenLayers 3 Vector Layer loses styling when map pans or zooms

Tags: javascript, gis, openlayers-3

**UPDATE**

I tried adding the files into a Snippet or JSFiddle to make it available to people to edit, but JSFiddle is banned and I cannot upload text files into a Snippet. Unless there's a better way to do it, [here's the public repo](https://gitlab.com/dheeraj-chand/ol3prototype) for the files.

Hi, everyone!

I'm working on switching from OpenLayers 2 to OpenLayers 3 and supplementing my reading of by trying some things out on my own. There's a project that I'm building [here](http://www.tandooriallstars.com/tom/index.php) that should be fairly simple: take form inputs and use them as parameters for building a vector layer. The interface works as intended, save for one problem.

Whenever I pan the map or zoom it, the vector layer seems to disappear. I can't for the life of me imagine what's going on. Anyone able to help me figure out what I can do to keep the layer in place?

Thanks!

Dheeraj

Comment: Try to come up with a more minimal example that exposes the issue, and make your snippet not require external data. The way it is now, it will be hard for anyone to answer.

Comment: Good point, I'll refactor the comment to use StackOverflow Snippets instead and link to a live example inline.

Comment: @ahocevar I'm not sure that there is a more minimal example: the whole thing is based on adding a layer as a result of form inputs, which is breaking. Adding the layers normally does not cause this problem, so I am not precisely sure what the problem is. Also I could not figure out how to add make an example work without external files, but I did make the repo publicly available and linked to it. Any help that you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was in line 77 [here](https://gitlab.com/dheeraj-chand/ol3prototype/blob/84d754e074e334177c876a6b435187e3f4a4b090/mapit.js). It turns out that for whatever reason, I misunderstood falsiness in JavaScript and my style-builder function was erring on undefined styles. Who knew? The rest of the code works, though!!!

Big thanks to @ahocevar for being willing to help!